# How to use Threading to set an gif background in tkinter?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am trying to implement this method with threading because whenever I press a button in my GUI the background gif stops playing for that instant.

piece of code I am trying to run using threading , so the gif animation in background also keeps running smoothly:

code below

```
im = PIM.open("Images\\backgroundalex.gif")

ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

gif = Label(window, image=ph, bg="black",bd="0")

gif.image = ph

framnr = 48

frames = [PhotoImage(file="Images\\backgroundalex.gif",
                     format='gif -index %i' % (i)) for i in range(framnr)]


def update1(ind):

     frame = frames[ind]

     ind += 1

     if ind > 47:



          ind = 0
     gif.configure(image = frame)
     window.after(100, update1, ind)


gif = Label(window)

gif.pack()

window.after(0, update1, 0)
```

Comment: You can't update your GUI from a thread.  All GUI manipulations must be done in the main thread.  If you have computations to do, those can be farmed to a thread.

Comment: Using thread does not help because the update of the GIF image is handled by tkinter `mainloop`.  If the `mainloop` does not take back control due to long running process in the main thread, it cannot update the GIF animation.